# Queue of delegates with a parameter

Tags: c#, delegates, queue

This problem is sort of complex for me, I'm not a C# guru.

Basically I have a Queue of some tasks I would like to handle. I want to be able to push various methods to that Queue, they will do different things, but all will take one string as a parameter. The question: how can I achieve this with the use of delegates? I'm not sure how to do this so the compiler doesn't throw any errors.

The code that more or less ilustrates what I want to do:

```
 delegate void Del(string);
 Queue<Del> Q = new Queue<Del>();

 public DT()
 {

        string foo = "bar";


        Q.Enqueue((foo) =>
        {
            //do some stuff
        });

 }
 //somewhere else I constantly check the queue and run the tasks
```

This design may seem bizarre, but in that regard I'm sure what I'm doing.

So, this gives a compiler error that a local variable foo cannot be declared. Of course I don't want to declare it, I want to sort of pass it to the function being pushed on the queue. What should I do?

I hope you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to provide the string when you enqueue the function, or when you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate type forms the signature for the final call.  Since you've said the string is provided when you enqueue it, the signature for the call is

```
delegate void Del();
Queue<Del> Q = new Queue<Del>();
```

Now to enqueue:

```
public DT()
{
    string foo = "bar";

    Q.Enqueue(() =>
    {
        //do some stuff using foo
    });
}
```

The value of `foo` is in scope inside the lambda, and will be captured into the delegate before it is enqueued.  This is called a *closure*.

Note that you could just use the predefined delegate type `System.Action` instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 3):

Just use different name of lambda argument (currently it conflicts with local `foo` variable declaration):

```
 Q.Enqueue(f => { 
     //do some stuff
 });
```

Then later you can get delegate from queue an pass parameter to it:

```
 Q.Dequeue()(foo);
```

If you want to capture value of `foo` variable, then just use it in *do some stuff* part. In this case you probably want delegate with signature, which does not accept any input parameters:

```
 Queue<Action> actions = new Queue<Action>();
 string foo = "bar";
 actions.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine(foo));
 actions.Dequeue()();
```

BTW: You don't need to create these delegates - use existing `Action<T>` or `Action` delegates.